# sed include files with no suffix

Tags: sed, wildcards

My sed command seems to exclude files with no suffix

```
sed -i.bak 's>/media/colic/>/media/>g' *.*
```

includes "filename.sh" but not "filename"

```
sed -i.bak 's>/media/colic/>/media/>g' *
```

Pulls up sed help, suggesting I need help (hence this question)

```
sed -i.bak 's>/media/colic/>/media/>g' '*'
```

tells me there are no files to be found

I could keep guessing, but I feel its better to ask what it is I dont understand.

Comment: `sed -i.bak 's>/media/colic/>/media/>g' *` is essentially correct (although the expansion of `*` will include any directories, which may cause sed to output some errors). The fact that it "pulls up sed help" suggests the directory you're working in contains one or more files whose names start with a hyphen - which sed is mistaking for options that it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string like `*.*` after your command is a globbing pattern, not a regular expression. It looks similar but it's not. For example `.` in a regexp means "any character" while `.` in a globbing pattern means "literal ." and `?` in a regexp is the equivalent that means "any character".

So in your command lines:

1. `*.*` = any file name that contains "." surrounded by any characters,
2. `*` = all files in your current directory, and
3. `'*'` = the file that's literally named `*`.

When I say "file" above that includes directories. Google "globbing patterns" for more information on their syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

If I understand correctly simply specifying * should work as it means all files in the cirrent directory. I tried this on an empty directory, and it fails with the same error. If I create a file (file.txt) it then works as expected.

OK, so there is something in the directory it doesnt like (I cant find any filenames begining with - though).

My question then becomes how can I run my SED replace on all files in the directory without it failing?

Comment: You're welcome. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) are discouraged and I think what I posted answered the question you asked in which case you should accept it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and ask a new question specifically about that if after doing some investigation yourself you need more help.

Comment: OK, no problem - Im happy to follow the rules :-) Im not sure I understand yet why its throwing the error but Ill repost that question. Thanks for all the help

Comment: And to help anyone else faced with the same issue, there werent  any names starting with hypens in the directory. I couldnt work out why * didn't work despite being the correct syntax as per Ed's answer. So I got round the problem by relieving sed of the burden of correctly interpreting * as all files in the directory and gave it to find instead:           find -type f -exec sed -i.bak2 's?/media/colic/?/media/?g' {} \;